# file compare in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl .

I have two text files:

file1 contain two lines:

```
mahesh
bharti
```

file2 contain two lines:

```
mahesh
orange
```

as you can see difference between two files is `bharti` and `orange`. Somehow i am able to print the difference. But my requirement is it should print as below.

```
Difference of file as below:
File1 contain: bharti
FIle2 contain: orange
```

my current code written in perl as below

Comment: I can see why that code is not working for you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ADiff) module.